# Which operations is the set of generalized hypergeometric functions closed under?

Tags: hypergeometric-function

Consider the set of all generalized hypergeometric functions.  I am trying to figure out which operations this set is closed under.  For example, is the sum of two generalized hypergeometric functions equal to another generalized hypergeometric function?  I am most interested in the "common" operations: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, composition, differentiation, and antidifferentiation.  I am sure that someone has written a paper on this topic, but there is so much information about the generalized hypergeometric function that it is hard to work through it all.  I would appreciate any information or links on the subject.  Thanks!

Comment: By "generalized hypergeometric function" do you mean a ${}_pF_q$ function or something else?  There are many possible generalizations.

Comment: Yes, that's the version I was thinking of.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "generalized hypergeometric function" you mean a series $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n x^n$ where $\alpha_{n+1}/\alpha_n$ is a rational function of $n$, then this is not closed under addition, subtraction, multiplication, division or composition.
For example, take $f(x) = \sum_n x^n = 1/(1-x)$ and $g(x) = \sum_n 2^n x^n = 1/(1-2x)$ which are generalized hypergeometric, but $f+g$, $f-g$, $fg$, $f/g$, $g \circ f$ are not.  They are closed under differentiation.